# ContactUp event not fired

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

In my surface application I have a SurfaceWindow with a SurfaceUserControl on. On the SurfaceUserControl I have a SurfaceButton but the ContactUp (and down) event is not fired. The ContactHoldGesture event is fired though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please, add the source code into your question?

Answer (score 3):

Could you include some code to reproduce? Where are you subscribing to those events?

Most likely what's happening is the contact up and down events are being handled by the button, so they don't fire at the usercontrol level. Try looking at the previewcontactup and previewcontactdown events.

Answer (score 1):

ContactUp and ContactDown are handled by the button itself - that's why the events never get to your code.  If you really want to intercept these events, use PreviewContactUp/PreviewContactDown instead.  What you probably really need though is to just handle the Click event on the button.  Adjust the ClickMode property of the button if you want to change what causes the Click event to be raised.